# Grouping the processors of a route together in a sequencial order for camel context

Tags: java, jvm, apache-camel, hawtio

I am trying to group all the processors of a route together in a camel context.

In the sense,I am reading the JVM metrics to get all the processors in the Camel context and I tried to filter these metrics by grouping  the processors pertaining to route names(meaning all the processors with the route name "**transfer_route**" are grouped together ).But the issue is that, I want the processor names to be in a sequential way(means the processors items in the route name "**transer_route**" must be in the order of their executions).Is there a way to do it ???

Eg:

```
 from("file:data1?noop=true").id("transfer_route").setHeader("acdee","reeee").process(new FileTransfer).to("direct:merge");
```

For this route,i tried to get the metrics through JVM and tries to group these processors metrics but the order of the processors list or not in the order of their execution (i.e, setHeader-->process-->to).Is there a way to put these thing in the order of their execution (kind of like HawtIO route Diagram,listing the processors in the order of their execution) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a index of each processor as a JMX attribute so you can order them in the same order as defined in the routes.

I think the attribute is called `ProcessorIndex`. The dump routes as XML operations include this information also.

Comment: There is an Attribute called   *Index* in each of these processors but they are not in the right order of there execution.Their numbering is done by the way of thread executions, if multiple routes are  written in a single camel context then these numbering is messing up.      Example :  `rest(URI_BASE_PATH)
                .get(URI_REST_ADCALL)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)
                .to(URI_DIRECT_AD_CALL);
`  .In this route **restBinding** is indexed 129 and **to** is indexed 117 .